# Why isn't this Config API Code saving options?

Tags: 8, forms

I can see the form, using the Config API, and submit it. However, it doesn't save the changes. Here is my code:

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\my_config\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class MyConfigForm extends ConfigFormBase {


  public function getFormId () {
    return 'my_config_settings';
  }

  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'my_config.config',
    ];
  }


  public function buildForm (array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    $form['author_config'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => \Drupal::config('config.factory')->get('author_config'),
      '#title' => 'Author of Config',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['language'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Language',
      '#options' => array(
        'EN' => t('English'),
        'SP' => t('Spanish'),
        'FR' => t('French'),
        'DE' => t('German'),
      ),
    );
    $form['drink'] = array (
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Select your drink',
      '#options' => array(
        'RB' => t('Root Beer'),
        'SD' => t('Sunny Delight'),
        'WR' => t('Water'),
        'OJ' => t('Orange Juice'),
      ),
    );
    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }


  public function submitForm (array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('my_config.config')->set('author_config', $form_state->getValue('author_config'))
     ->set('language', $form_state->getValue('language'))
         ->set('drink', $form_state->getValue('drink'))->save();
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }

}
```

This is my routing file:

```
my_config.settings:
  path: '/my-config/config'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\my_config\Form\MyConfigForm'
    _title: 'Configuration Form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

Comment: I think you're setting the values correctly, but the default values for your form elements are being retrieved incorrectly.

Comment: What are you using to check that the values are(n't) saved? If it's the same form (after the save), you forgot the `#default_value` for the `language` and `drink`

Comment: Also you should ideally use `$this->config('...')->get()` and `$this->config('...')->set()` rather than the global method; it shouldn't work any differently, but for the sake of DI and testability it's a simple change

Comment: It is the same form, and I will be adding it to drink and language too. I just noticed the problem with the author_config field first. Thanks for the $this->config('...')->get tip. I'll be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
'#default_value' => \Drupal::config('config.factory')->get('author_config'),
```

It should be:

```
'#default_value' => \Drupal::config('my_config.config')->get('author_config'),
```

This is the entire form:

```
$form['author_config'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => \Drupal::config('my_config.config')->get('author_config'),
  '#title' => 'Author of Config',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['language'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Language',
  '#default_value' => \Drupal::config('my_config.config')->get('language'),
  '#options' => array(
    'EN' => t('English'),
    'SP' => t('Spanish'),
    'FR' => t('French'),
    'DE' => t('German'),
  ),
);
$form['drink'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'Select your drink',
  '#default_value' => \Drupal::config('my_config.config')->get('drink'),
  '#options' => array(
    'RB' => t('Root Beer'),
    'SD' => t('Sunny Delight'),
    'WR' => t('Water'),
    'OJ' => t('Orange Juice'),
  ),
);
```

Probably using $this->config the problem will be solved too

Comment: So would \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('my_config.config')->set  be $this->config('my_config.config')->set

Comment: Yes, and \Drupal::config('my_config.config')->get('author_config') will be $this->config('my_config.config')->get('author_config')